# Copy location constraint while maintaining the original distance

Tags: python, animation, constraints

I have two empties `Emp_Anim` and `Emp_toFollow`, where one is animated and the other is not as shown in my .blend file found [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/w8dgzrf7r2zkxbj/empty_track.blend?dl=0). How can I make the `Emp_toFollow` apply the same transform location and rotation of the `Emp_Anim`? For example, at frame 1 they are apart from each other with a certain initial distance (x,y,z), I want `Emp_toFollow` follow the location and rotation of `Emp_Anim` while maintaining the same initial separation distance that existed at frame 1. Like I want to apply the two constraints `copy_location` and `track_to` but  also have the initial separation xyz distance existing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to achieve this, but the easiest and most straight forward would be to check Offset option in Copy Location constraint and move the Emp_toFollow back to it's original position. Like this:[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you tell me what are the other possible ways of doing this? I also wonder how it can be done in python please?

Comment: Other ways would be as you mentioned python, using limit distance constraint, by parenting both empties to opposite vertices of curve or edge, using drivers and probably some other of which I didn't thought.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll stick to your answer. I've applied it as shown here in my .blend here https://www.dropbox.com/s/ijitjrf2ti4817n/empty_track2.blend?dl=0 . I have two questions please. 1- If I moved to the next frame the empties parented to `Bottom` & `Middle` empties will snap away to different locations, I don't know why and how I can I avoid this? 2- If you select `Bone1` and rotate it around X +180, you will find that the empties following the `Bottom` empty are now above the `Bottom` empty while before rotating `Bone1` they were below, so how I can maintain their original position

Comment: I'd appreciate it if you could advise me please? and please let me know if it's not clear so I can explain better what I mean. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: You made quite a mess there. Each of the empties have their own animation plus they still having constraints and this both influences are working in the same time, creating weird behaviour.The best way to ensure of keeping the same angle to the bone is to use other bones, set in appropriate angle.

Comment: oh okay, so I'll have to delete their old animation first, right? then for those other empties, I'll have to parent them to the location of a new bone, right? Thank you